# Webpart, persisting boolean properties

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I've created a webpart with a lot of properties. All the properties (enums, strings) are persisted just fine when the following attributes are added:

```
    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
    [WebBrowsable(true)]
```

apart from the boolean properties. When the webpart is edited again the stored values for those properties aren't retrieved. Is this behaviour unique to boolean properties?

The property definition is a plain, automatic bool property. In some cases the DefaultValue attribute is applied.

thanks

Comment: No, even the boolean properties should be persisted. Can you post some code ...

Comment: provide your property definition for Bool including the definition of private variable